# Time (hours) formatting when plotting GAM smooth effects with mgcViz

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam, mgcv

I have a GAM model where time of day is one of the predictor values. Time is in numeric format, since as far as I understand, `mgcv::gam` doesn't accept POSIXct class. The model works fine, but I'd like to see a plot where smooth effect has HH:MM on the X-axis, instead of the continuous UNIX epoch. I'm using `mgcViz` for plotting.

How could I get nice time formats (HH/HH:MM) on the X-axis labels?

Reproducible example:

```
require(mgcv)
require(mgcViz)

min_datetime <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2021-12-27 06:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
max_datetime <- as.POSIXct(strptime("2021-12-27 18:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
tod <- runif(100, min = as.numeric(min_datetime), max = as.numeric(max_datetime))

df <- data.frame(x, y, tod)

mod <- gam(y ~ x + tod, data = df)

viz_mod <- getViz(mod)

plot_mod <- plot(viz_mod, select = 2) +
  l_fitLine(linetype = 1)

# Epoch on X-axis, should be HH:MM
print(plot_mod)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mgcViz` is a wrapper around `ggplot2`, you can use standard `ggplot2::scale_...` functions to manipulate your labels, breaks, or anything else you want in the plot. Here we can use `scale_x_continuous` to convert the numeric `x` axis back to `POSIXct` and then format it as you desire.

```r
plot_mod +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ~ format(as.POSIXct(.x, origin = origin), "%H:%M"))
```

[image]